# Structure of Niobium and Tantalum carbonyls

Tags: molecular-structure, carbonyl-complexes

$\ce{V(CO)6}$ is well known to be an unusual 17 valence electron, paramagnetic octahedral complex.

Do the corresponding tantalum and niobium species form simple dimers or more complicated structures ?

Answer (score 3):

From the abstract of *J. Chem. Theory Comput.*, **2011**, 
*7*, 2112-2125 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ct2003513)) is seems that niobium forms a dinuclear $\ce{Nb2(CO)12}$ complex, in which two $\ce{Nb(CO)6}$ units are connected by a 340 pm $\ce{Nb-Nb}$ bond.